# Find Laplace Transform of exponential function using unit step function and t-shifting. (5.3-42)

Tags: laplace-transform, solution-verification

Please check my work. Did I calculate the following Laplace Transform correctly?

$$f(t)=e^{kt}u(t-a)$$

**My solution**:

Use the following corollary from the second shifting theorem (t-shift)...

$$\mathcal{L}\{g(t)u(t-a)\}=e^{-as}\mathcal{L}\{g(t+a)\}$$

where...

$$f(t)=g(t+a)$$

with $g(t)=e^{kt}$ and $a=a$

$$g(t+a)=e^{k(t+a)}=e^{kt}e^{ka}$$

$$\mathcal{L}\{e^{kt}u(t-a)\}=e^{-as}\cdot \mathcal{L}\{e^{ka}e^{kt}\}$$

$$e^{-as}\cdot e^{ka}\mathcal{L}\{e^{kt}=e^{-a(s-k)}\cdot \mathcal{L}\{e^{kt}\}$$

$$F(s)=\frac{e^{-a(s-k)}}{s-k}$$

Comment: The solution is correct!

Comment: Thank you for checking it.

Comment: You are welcome.